# why i have this wierd problem about my route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

i'm working on a livewire project based on laravel ... every think was normal till yesterday my project didn't find some route and i recieved 404 .

for example one of my routes is  /category/index

```
use App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Home as AdminPanel;
use App\Http\Livewire\AdminAuth\Register as AdminRegister;
use App\Http\Livewire\AdminAuth\Login as AdminLogin;
use App\Http\Livewire\AdminAuth\ForgotPassword as AdminForgotPassword;
use App\Http\Livewire\Category\Create as AddCategory;
use App\Http\Livewire\Category\Categories as Cats;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/home',AdminPanel::class)->middleware('auth')->name('Home');
Route::get('/admin/register',AdminRegister::class)->name('Admin.Register');
Route::get('/admin/login',AdminLogin::class)->name('Admin.Login');
Route::get('/admin/forgot-password',AdminForgotPassword::class)->name('Admin.ForgotPassword');
Route::get('/category/create',AddCategory::class)->name('create.category');
Route::get('/category/index',IndexCategory::class)->name('index.category');
```

my controller :

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Category;

use App\Models\Category;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Index extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    public $cat_id;
    protected $listeners=['cat_id'=>'CatID'];

    public function CatID($id){
        $this->cat_id=$id;
    }
    public function render()
    {
        $cat=Category::findOrFail($this->cat_id);
        $categories=Category::with('childrenRecursive')->where('parent_id',null)->paginate(15);
        return view('livewire.category.index',compact('categories','cat'))->extends('layouts.admin')->section('content');
    }
}
```

i tried all optimization artisan code like clear cache and  clear route but it didn't work

Comment: Does the route appear in the routes table and have you tried clearning your caches just to be sure?

Comment: With anything route related run php artisan route:list to see how the route are registred in the app

Comment: IndexCategory in the route and Index as livewire component??? It's a typo???